# Read content from website

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I want this data from the site `(export.benzinpreis-aktuell.de/exportdata.txt?code=e0bDB27ekW83a95)` and I don´t know how to do.

With

```
System.open_url(export.benzinpreis-aktuell.de/exportdata.txt?code=e0bDB27ekW83a95)
```

I can open the page, but when i want to read the data it doesn't work.

Also I have tried this,

```
      require 'uri'
      require 'net/http'

  def read
    r = Net::HTTP.get_reponse( URI.parse('http://export.benzinpreis-aktuell.de/exportdata.txt?code=e0bDB27ekW83a95') ) 
   redirect :action => :index 
  end
```

But I get the error message

```
require_compiled: error: can not find net/http
App error: no such file to load -- net/http
```

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `net-http` and `uri` in your `build.yml` file (in extensions section), because these libraries are not included/compiled by default in a rhodes build:

```
extensions: 
- net-http
- uri
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
require 'open-uri'

file = open('http://your.url.goes.here.com/page/whatever')
result = file.read
puts result
```